# Background colour of chess pieces

Tags: java, android, chess

I have downloaded all the eight pieces from Google images for both black and white player. All the images have a white background. I saved the images of the pieces in the drawable folder. I want to place a white Pawn on a black sqaure. Hence, I did the following:

```
<TextView
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tv70"
    android:background="@drawable/white_pawn"
/>
```

I have left out the unnecessary details regarding the position of the textview. The textview was supposed to be of a black background but the image of the rook makes it a white square(because it has a white background).

If I have to make it on a black background, I have to go and use Paint or Photoshop and change each of the background colour of the pieces to black and save them. (Giving me 20 images of such pieces). It takes alot of memory.

How should I change the background colour of the pieces without having so many images files? Or this there another way of creating the pieces for my chess game?

I'm attaching a picture of my Pawn pieces.

[image: 4 different images of a pawn on different background and piece colour]

The above image is when I use the image with black and white background separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different colors than black and white for tiles. Otherwise it will break eyes.

P.S. You can use fonticons like https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=chess

Comment: So using these icons won't interfere with the original background image?

Comment: If colors will black and white, then it will be same result. But you can change icons` borders and colors dynamically.

Comment: It does not work. I downloaded the knights icon. The black background image turned white.

Comment: You need to configure itself. Like borders and something.